# React Bootstrap table : not able to update checkbox value when using dataFormat on one of the table columns

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react bootstrap table and have "Status" as one of the columns in the table. This column is formatted using dataFormat tag and i have written a function to display render the checkbox. Something like this :

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='STATUS' dataFormat={statusFormatter}>Column name</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Now i want to update the value of the checkbox. But i think statusFormatter being a function does not provide me handle to update the value of a checkbox.

Here is my code for the function :

```
function statusFormatter(cell, row) {
let checkBoxValue = false;

if (cell==='RESOLVED')
     checkBoxValue = true;  

return (
    <CheckBoxForTable active={checkBoxValue} onToggle={this.onStatusUpdate.bind(this)}/>
)
}
```

I am getting the following error: 
Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Can anybody guide me how to update the checkbox value and send an action to the server.

Comment: Where is `onStatusUpdate` function in your `statusFormatter`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around, Just pass `onStatusUpdate` of your component to `formatter` function

```
<TableHeaderColumn 
   dataField='STATUS' 
   dataFormat={(cell, row) => statusFormatter(cell, row, this.onStatusUpdate.bind(this))}
>Column name</TableHeaderColumn>
```

and your formatter

```
function statusFormatter(cell, row, onStatusUpdate) {
let checkBoxValue = false;

if (cell==='RESOLVED')
     checkBoxValue = true;  

return (
    <CheckBoxForTable active={checkBoxValue} onToggle={onStatusUpdate}/>
)
}
```

Comment: It gives an error - Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined at dataFormat

Comment: Where is your `onStatusUpdate` method?

Comment: onStatusUpdate is defined in the constructor of the component where the table component is present.

Comment: Can I see the `table` component?